# Django sending email

Tags: python, django, email

In PHP I can send an email simply by calling `mail()`. In Django, I need to specify SMTP backends and other things.

Is there a simpler way to send email from Django?

Comment: The only reason you didn't have to specify the SMTP settings in PHP was because someone else had already done the work for you when they setup the webserver. *All email* is sent via SMTP. The only question is which SMTP server will accept a connection from your client and how does your client authenticate itself to the server. Your local syadmin should be able to provide this information in about 10 seconds flat. (OK, maybe 20 seconds.)

Comment: ok, I found the info in php.ini, but now sending emails is VERY slow.

Comment: How did you measure that it VERY slow ?

Comment: I send my form and wait 10-15 seconds until page loads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several good mail-sending functions in the `django.core.mail` module.

For a tutorial please see [Sending e-mail](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/):

> Although Python makes sending e-mail
>   relatively easy via the smtplib
>   library, Django provides a couple of
>   light wrappers over it. These wrappers
>   are provided to make sending e-mail
>   extra quick, to make it easy to test
>   e-mail sending during development, and
>   to provide support for platforms that
>   can’t use SMTP.

The simplest function that would most likely suit your purposes is the [`send_mail`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) function:

```
send_mail(
    subject, 
    message, 
    from_email, 
    recipient_list, 
    fail_silently=False, 
    auth_user=None, 
    auth_password=None, 
    connection=None)
```

Comment: "Mail is sent using the SMTP host and port specified in the EMAIL_HOST and EMAIL_PORT settings." ??

Comment: Well you need to specify who will be sending your email - even PHP cannot send email without _some_ sort of SMTP server configured at some location for sending email.

Comment: ok, I found the info in php.ini, but now sending emails is VERY slow.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can only send mail with a simple mail() command on non-Windows systems. These will expect a local MTA like Postfix to be installed and correctly configured, as should be the case for most web servers. If you want to depend on third-party or decentralized mail service depends on how critical email is for your application. Serious dependency on speedy and reliable email transmission usually results in sending mail via SMTP to a central mail server (the "big pipe").

Still, if you want to have the same function as in PHP, try this:

```
import subprocess

def send_mail(from_addr, to_addr, subject, body):
  cmdline = ["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-f"]
  cmdline.append(from_addr)
  cmdline.append(to_addr)
  mailer = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  dialog = "From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s\n.\n" % (from_addr, to_addr, subject, body)
  return mailer.communicate(dialog)
```

And use it like:
`send_mail ("Me <myself@mydomain.com>", "Recip Ient <other@hisdomain.com>", "Teh' Subject", "Mail body")`

Answer (score 0):

Either way, you need some backend (read MTA). Of the top of my head I can think of two things:

1. As already pointed out, you can for example use sendmail http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1864/
2. Even better, use a Python MTA. There's Lamson, a Python email server (MTA): http://lamsonproject.org/docs/hooking_into_django.html